# Interact with Session type Kernel objects

Tags: c++, windows, driver, kernel-module

This is my first time dealing with Windows kernel objects so please correct me if the terminology or what I say it's not accurate

I'm trying to open and send some data to a Session type kernel object named `\KernelObjects\\Session0`.

From Windows Internals book:

> KernelObjects [...] Contains event objects that signal kernel pool resource conditions,
> the completion of certain operating system tasks, **as well as Session
> objects (at least Session0) representing each interactive session**,
> and Partition objects (at least MemoryPartition0) for each memory
> partition.

The `Session0` type object exist as can be seen in `WinObj`:

[image: WinObj screenshot]

Below is the code I wrote to:

- Open the object
- Send user data to the object
- Close the object

```
#include <winternl.h>
#include <stdio.h>


struct driverData
{
    [...] ;
};

typedef NTSTATUS(WINAPI* NTOpenEventAPI)(
    OUT PHANDLE EventHandle,
    IN ACCESS_MASK DesiredAccess,
    IN POBJECT_ATTRIBUTES ObjectAttributes);

typedef NTSTATUS(WINAPI* NtNotifyChangeSession)(_In_ HANDLE SessionHandle, _In_ ULONG ChangeSequenceNumber, _In_ PLARGE_INTEGER ChangeTimeStamp,
    _In_ int Event, _In_ int NewState, _In_ int PreviousState,
    _In_reads_bytes_opt_(PayloadSize) PVOID Payload, _In_ ULONG PayloadSize);

typedef NTSTATUS(WINAPI* NtClose1)(_In_ HANDLE);


static
HANDLE OpenKernelSession(const wchar_t* event_name, OUT HANDLE* session) {
    static HMODULE ntdll = ::GetModuleHandleW(L"ntdll.dll");
    static const auto NtOpenSessionFunc = (NTOpenEventAPI)::GetProcAddress(ntdll, "NtOpenSession");
    if (!NtOpenSessionFunc) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot load NtOpenSession function. Error: %u\n", ::GetLastError());
        return NULL;
    }

    static const auto RtlInitUnicodeStringFunc =
        reinterpret_cast<decltype(&::RtlInitUnicodeString)>(GetProcAddress(ntdll, "RtlInitUnicodeString"));
    if (!RtlInitUnicodeStringFunc) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot load RtlInitUnicodeString function. Error: %u\n", ::GetLastError());
        return NULL;
    }

    UNICODE_STRING object_name;
    RtlInitUnicodeStringFunc(&object_name, event_name);

    OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES object_attrib;
    InitializeObjectAttributes(&object_attrib, &object_name, 0, nullptr, nullptr);


    //HANDLE session;
    NTSTATUS status = NtOpenSessionFunc(session, 2, &object_attrib);
    if (!NT_SUCCESS(status)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot open event %S. Error: 0x%08X\n", event_name, status);
        return NULL;
    }
    else {
        printf("Success opening object %S\n", event_name);
    }
    return session;
}

static
HANDLE notifyChangeSession(HANDLE* session) {
    static HMODULE ntdll = ::GetModuleHandleW(L"ntdll.dll");
    static const auto NtNotifyChangeSessionFunc = (NtNotifyChangeSession)::GetProcAddress(ntdll, "NtNotifyChangeSession");
    if (!NtNotifyChangeSessionFunc) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot load NtNotifyChangeSession function. Error: %u\n", ::GetLastError());
        return NULL;
    }


    static const auto RtlInitUnicodeStringFunc =
        reinterpret_cast<decltype(&::RtlInitUnicodeString)>(GetProcAddress(ntdll, "RtlInitUnicodeString"));
    if (!RtlInitUnicodeStringFunc) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot load RtlInitUnicodeString function. Error: %u\n", ::GetLastError());
        return NULL;
    }
   
    struct driverData drdata;

    NTSTATUS status = NtNotifyChangeSessionFunc(session, 0, 0, 1,
        4, 4, &drdata, sizeof(struct driverData));

    if (!NT_SUCCESS(status)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error calling NtNotifyChangeSessionFunc. Error: 0x%08X\n", status);
        return NULL;
    }
    else {
        printf("Success calling NtNotifyChangeSessionFunc\n");
    }

    return nullptr; // ToDo change  
}


static
int closeSession(HANDLE& session) {
    static HMODULE ntdll = ::GetModuleHandleW(L"ntdll.dll");
    static const auto NtCloseFunc = (NtClose1)::GetProcAddress(ntdll, "NtClose");
    if (!NtCloseFunc) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot load NtCloseFunc function. Error: %u\n", ::GetLastError());
        return -1;
    }

    NTSTATUS status = NtCloseFunc(session);

    if (!NT_SUCCESS(status)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot close session\n");
        return -1;
    }
    else {
        printf("Success closing session\n");
    }

    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    HANDLE session = { 0 };
    OpenKernelSession(L"\\KernelObjects\\Session0", &session);

    notifyChangeSession(&session);

    Sleep(2000);

    return closeSession(session);
}
```

Opening the object works fine but calling `NtNotifyChangeSession` errors with:

`STATUS_INVALID_HANDLE  0xC0000008  An invalid HANDLE was specified.`

I guess two things may be happening:

- The code above is wrong: if so, can you help me localizing the bug?
- Whatever driver that is in charge of consuming the data I send with `NtNotifyChangeSession` may be doing some checking in the data I send and returning `STATUS_INVALID_HANDLE`. If that's the case, how can I find the code in charge of that checking? It's ok if I have to reverse engineer some binary as long as I get to the root cause.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Your `notifyChangeSession()` function takes a pointer to a handle instead of a handle.

Comment: You are right! How stupid that was xD
Thank you so much. If you want to write a simple reply I'll flag it as correct so you can get the bounty. Thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `notifyChangeSession()` function takes a pointer to a handle instead of a handle.